Better to repot even in winter or wait until spring?
I have a bunch of long-neglected houseplants (Dracaena marginata, Dypsis lutescens, Scindapsus aureus, Monstera deliciosa) that are very sad because they haven't been repotted in about five years.
I finally have the time and space to do something about this but have always thought repotting should be done in Spring.
What's the least bad option here?
(And tips for repotting neglected plants, compost choice, root care, etc. appreciated).

They are houseplants. So they don't really get seasons; waiting for spring is just another half a year they are waiting for the already overdue repotting.
